# InvalidCIDRNotation while creating Virtual Network in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network, subnet

I use a bicep script to create a virtual network and 3 subnets

```
param vnetName string = 'vnet'

@description('The IP address range for virtual network')
param vnetAddressPrefix string = '10.201.0.0/16' //This value cannot be changed as it is used for deploying a containerApp

param subnetname string = 'subnet-app'
@description('The IP address space used for app subnet.')
param appSubnetAddressPrefix string = '10.201.0.0/23' //this subnet range cannot be changed as used for deploying containerApp

param privatesubnet string = 'subnet-pe'
@description('The IP address space used ')
param privatesubnetaddressprefix string = '10.201.1.0/23'

param assetsubnet string = 'subnnet-assets'
@description('The IP address space used for subnet asset.')
param assetsnet string = '10.201.2.0/23'
```

When i run the bicep file which should create 1 Virtual network and 3 subnets i get this
error.

```
"code": "InvalidTemplateDeployment", "message": "The template deployment 'exdeploy' is not valid according to the validation procedure. The tracking id is 'adfd-1e75eedfd40fa-32343-dderese1232'. See inner errors for details."}

Inner Errors: 
{"code": "InvalidCIDRNotation", "target": "/subscriptions/dysd/resourceGroups/mygrp/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vnet-edersede", "message": "The address prefix 10.201.1.0/23 in resource /subscriptions/dysd/resourceGroups/mygrp/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vnet-edersede/subnets/subnet-pe has an invalid CIDR notation. For the given prefix length, the address prefix should be 10.201.0.0/23."}
```

No resource gets created
Can anyone help here? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I created Bicep file in My Local and  the below code is filled in this file.

```
param location string = resourceGroup().location
resource vnet 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks@2021-08-01' = {
  name: 'devvnet'
  location: resourceGroup().location
  properties: {
    addressSpace: {
      addressPrefixes: [
        '10.0.0.0/16'
      ]
    }
  }
}
resource subnet1 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets@2021-08-01' = {
  parent: vnet
  name: 'subnet1'
  properties: {
    addressPrefix: '10.0.4.0/23'
    networkSecurityGroup: {
      id: nsg1.id
    }
  }
}

resource nsg1 'Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups@2021-08-01' = {
  location: location
  name: 'nsg1'
}
```

- The above code ran successfully. check the below image.
  [image]

**Result :**
[image]

Comment: this cannot be used in my case as i need 1 subnet atleast in /23 and vnet should be /16

Comment: I have Edited the answer as of your requirements. please check.

Answer (score 0):

Use any CIDR calculator([example](https://www.ipaddressguide.com/cidr)).

10.201.0.0/23 has a starting IP of  10.201.0.0 and ending IP of 10.201.1.255. So your subnet 2 of 10.201.1.0/23 is actually overlapping subnet 1.

You can configure the following non-overlapping CIDRs for your subnets. This will work.

Subnet 1 : 10.201.0.0/23

Subnet 2 : 10.201.2.0/23

Subnet 3 : 10.201.4.0/23